# Parâmetro opcional em função

Tags: python, funções, parâmetros

Fui tentar criar uma função de raiz quadrada:

```
def root(n, ind):
    if ind == None:
        ind = 2
    ind2 = 1 / ind
    print(n ** ind2)
```

Eu quero que o **`ind`** não seja obrigatório.

Eu pensei que se não colocasse, o valor iria virar `None` (por isso eu coloquei `if ind == none, ind = 2`, para poder transformar o `ind` em 2).

Tem alguma maneira, ou é impossível? Nem que seja com uma outra maneira sem ser `def`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem. Basta você atribuir, junto à definição da função, o valor que o parâmetro receberá por padrão.

```
def root(n, ind = 2):
    ind2 = 1 / ind
    print(n ** ind2)
```

Assim, se chamar `root(10, 5)`, `n` valerá 10 e `ind` valerá 5; se chamar apenas `root(10)`, o valor de `ind` será 2, pois é o valor padrão. Vale ressaltar que os parâmetros opcionais **sempre** deverão estar após os parâmetros requeridos. Isto é, da forma acima é possível, mas fazer algo como:

```
def root(ind = 2, n):
    ...
```

Dará erro de sintaxe.

> SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument